# How to use JQuery in MVC Asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

Currently I am working in MVC ASP.NET.I have query what is purpose of JQUERY in HTTP GET and POST Methods.I found a code somewhere like this.

```
function checkPromRepNo() {

if (document.getElementById("PromRep1").value.trim() == "")
    document.getElementById('divPromRepDoesNotExist').style.display = 'none';
else {
    var promRepNo = $("#PromRep1").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: VirualURL + "/Register/ValidatePromRep",
        data: promRepNo,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.Message == "false")
                document.getElementById('divPromRepDoesNotExist').style.display = 'block';
            else
                document.getElementById('divPromRepDoesNotExist').style.display = 'none';
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("ERROR");
        }
    });
}
return false;
}
```

Could anyone tell me what is main use of JQUERY Ajax in MVC.

Comment: To get data to and from the server without a refresh.

Comment: I would encourage you to do some research before posting a question. Stackoverflow encourages you to do so as well. No offense.

Comment: StackOverflow is where you go when Google is no help. Do some research and stop looking for easy answers. This is for your own benefit. You'll learn 10 times more finding the answer yourself than you ever will being spoonfed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main use of that code is to create an Ajax request that will not cause your page to load or refresh. Furthermore, it will be managed asynchronically.

In other words, you can send a request to the server and process the response without the need to reload.

```
url: VirualURL + "/Register/ValidatePromRep"
```

This URL will be routed to a controller, which is going to recieve the variable promRepNo as input and return a response in JSON format. If the response is successful, then this function is going to process it's data:

```
function (data) {
    if (data.Message == "false")
        document.getElementById('divPromRepDoesNotExist').style.display = 'block';
    else
        document.getElementById('divPromRepDoesNotExist').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Remember that the controller can filter the request by it's type (POST) with the [HttpPost]
tag and identify that it was an Ajax request with HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()